Issues Handling Plain Identifiers in API Platform/Symfony
I am struggling to use plain identifiers in API Platform. I have related entities and have followed the official documentation of API Platform, creating a Denormalizer, but I always get the error Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\Address\
My goal is to work with plain IDs instead of IRIs (later I want to switch to UUIDs).
Current Request Body (POST)

{
  "name": "Test",
  "address": {
    "street": "Test",
    "zip": "11111",
    "city": "Test",
    "country": "Test",
    "type": "/api/address_types/1" //Address Type ID
  },
  "cover": "/api/medias/17" //Cover ID
  "type":  "/api/stores/1" // Store Type ID
}

Future Request Body (I have currently problem with this)
{
  "name": "Test",
  "address": {
    "street": "Test",
    "zip": "11111",
    "city": "Test",
    "country": "Test",
    "type": 1 //Address Type ID
  },
  "cover": 17 //Cover ID
  "type":  1 // Store Type ID
}

StoreEntity (Getters and Setters were not included in this example)
<?php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: StoreRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(normalizationContext: ['groups' => 'store_collection_read']),
        new Get(normalizationContext: ['groups' => 'store_item_read']),
        new Post(denormalizationContext: ['groups' => 'store:write']),
        new Put(denormalizationContext: ['groups' => 'store:write']),
        new Patch(denormalizationContext: ['groups' => 'store:write']),
        new Delete()
    ]
)]
class Store
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['store_collection_read', 'store_item_read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove', 'refresh'])]
    #[Groups(['store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?Address $address = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Media::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[ApiProperty(types: ['https://schema.org/image'])]
    #[Groups(['store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    public ?Media $cover = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[Groups(['store_item_read', 'store:write', 'refresh'])]
    private ?StoreType $type = null;

Address Entity (Getters and Setters were not included in this example)

class Address
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $street = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $additionalAddress = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $zip = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $city = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'store_collection_read', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?string $country = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'addresses')]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'store_item_read', 'store:write'])]
    private ?AddressType $type = null;

PlainIdentifierDenormalizer

class PlainIdentifierDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface, DenormalizerAwareInterface
{
    use DenormalizerAwareTrait;

    private IriConverterInterface $iriConverter;
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(IriConverterInterface $iriConverter, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->iriConverter = $iriConverter;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = []): mixed
    {
        if (isset($data['address']['type'])) {

            $data['address']['type'] =
                $this
                    ->iriConverter
                    ->getIriFromResource(
                        resource: Address::class,
                        context: ['uri_variables' => ['id' => $data['address']['type']]]
                    );
        }

        if (isset($data['cover'])) {
            $data['cover'] =
                $this
                    ->iriConverter
                    ->getIriFromResource(
                        resource: Media::class,
                        context: ['uri_variables' => ['id' => $data['cover']]]
                    );

        }

        if (isset($data['type'])) {
            $data['type'] =
                $this
                    ->iriConverter
                    ->getIriFromResource(
                        resource: StoreType::class,
                        context: ['uri_variables' => ['id' => $data['type']]]
                    );
        }

        return $this->denormalizer->denormalize($data, $class, $format, $context + [__CLASS__ => true]);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return \in_array($format, ['json', 'jsonld'], true) && is_a($type, Store::class, true) && !isset($context[__CLASS__]);
    }

    public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
    {
        return [
            'object' => null,
            '*' => false,
            Store::class => true
        ];
    }
}


It seems that the problem is in wrong resource class here
$data['address']['type'] =
                $this
                    ->iriConverter
                    ->getIriFromResource(
                        resource: Address::class,
                        context: ['uri_variables' => ['id' => $data['address']['type']]]
                    );

It should be AddressType instead of Address

Sadly it didn't work. Even when I remove that part with address type, I get the same error on other entities: Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\Media\

Hm, try to add #[Context(normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['store_item_read', 'store:write', 'refresh']])] to such properties, use the same groups as in Group attribute.
